# MySql - how to disallow duplicate entries where the only difference is case, using utf8_bin collation?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `user` and collation - `utf8_bin`:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(192) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    admin_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    UNIQUE KEY admin_id_user_name (admin_id,user_name),
    CONSTRAINT admin_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (admin_id) REFERENCES admin (admin_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I want to disallow to insert the same entries where the only difference is case. In my opinion `utf8_bin` collation should help me for this approach. 
But i does`t work. When i try to insert new entry, which differs from the previous one only in case, entry is inserted.

```
    user_id  | user_name | admin_id
    _______________________________
        1    |    name   |    1
    _______________________________
        2    |    Name   |    1
```

Do you know how to disallow this?

Comment: Have you tried with `COLLATE latin1_bin`

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal. utf8_bin compares value based on their unicode (check [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) for reference)

I you want to have a table with case sensitive data you could go for utf8_unicode_cs (case sensitive)

Note that utf8_bin and utf8_defaut_ci are case insensitive.

FYI: cs in all codification means case sensitive and ci means case insensitive.

Comment: But when i try to change it to utf8_unicode_cs, i get an error ERROR 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8_unicode_cs'